# command-line-arguments : handling "undefined" error message

Tags: go

Following is how the source files are organized

```
✘-1 ~/Go/src/github.com/krmahadevan/packages 
18:24 $ tree .
.
├── sample_main.go
└── sample_one.go

0 directories, 2 files
```

Here's how the source code looks like:

**sample_one.go**

```golang
package main

var data map[string]string

func init() {
    data = make(map[string]string, 0)
}
```

**sample_main.go**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    data["foo"] = "bar"
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Now when I attempt at running **sample_main.go** I get errors stating that `data` is undefined.

```
18:24 $ go run sample_main.go 
# command-line-arguments
./sample_main.go:6:2: undefined: data
./sample_main.go:7:14: undefined: data
✘-2 ~/Go/src/github.com/krmahadevan/packages
```

But when I build the code into a binary and then execute it, it runs fine.

```
✔ ~/Go/src/github.com/krmahadevan/packages 
18:27 $ go build
✔ ~/Go/src/github.com/krmahadevan/packages 
18:28 $ ./packages 
map[foo:bar]
✔ ~/Go/src/github.com/krmahadevan/packages
```

I would like to understand why is this behavior ?

Environment:

```
18:31 $ go version
go version go1.11.4 darwin/amd64
```

The closest I found was this post : [Golang : command-line-arguments undefined: variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381817/golang-command-line-arguments-undefined-variable)

But this post talks about scoped variables that are defined in `main`.

But my problem statement involves variables defined in another go file and accessed in the `main` method.

Comment: Sometimes there are multiple entry points and for all of them to run we need to run them all.

In Go (Unix-Based Terminal): `go run .` should suffice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To understand why, read the `go` command documentation:

> [Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> [Compile and run Go program](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go run [build flags] [-exec xprog] package [arguments...]
> ```
>
> Run compiles and runs the named main Go package. Typically the package
>   is specified as a list of .go source files, but it may also be an
>   import path, file system path, or pattern matching a single known
>   package, as in 'go run .' or 'go run my/cmd'.
>
> [Compile packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> Build compiles the packages named by the import paths, along with
>   their dependencies, but it does not install the results.
>
> If the arguments to build are a list of .go files, build treats them
>   as a list of source files specifying a single package.
>
> For more about specifying packages, see 'go help packages'. For more
>   about where packages and binaries are installed, run 'go help gopath'.

---

> `go run`: Typically the package is specified as a list of .go source files.

For your `go run` example, list the files:

```
go run sample_main.go sample_one.go
```

Comment: thanks for helping out with this question. That solved the problem. Just to add a bit more context, in case anyone is facing this issue when running from within an IDE such as GoLang IDE, one needs to edit configuration and choose `Run kind` as `Package`.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - unrelated comment. could you please help me in this testng question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196503/how-to-debug-testng-tests-which-use-dataproviders thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To fix it, just run the following command:

Windows: `go run *` or `go build *`

Unix: `go run .` or `go build .`

You are going to run it inside the folder of the files you want to use.