# How to debug testng tests which use dataproviders?

Tags: java, testng

I have a testng test method which uses a dataprovider to get test inputs. I want to debug the test only when the test runs for the 2nd test data input. How do I do that ? How should I set the breakpoint ?

Here is some sample code.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "myDataProvider")
public void findStringInString(String input, String toFind, boolean found){
    Assert.assertEquals(finder(input, toFind), found, "Could not find " + toFind + " in " + input);
}

@DataProvider(name = "myDataProvider")
public static Object[][] stringSource()
{
    return new Object[][] {
        {"hello", "hell", true},
        {"nice", "iced", false},
        {etc...}
    };
}
```

PS - As an aside, does this code look like an anti-pattern or bad practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of determining where to setup the debug point is to maintain a counter that checks which data provider iteration is being run and then when the value reaches your desired value, do a debug print statement and set the breakpoint in that line.

Here's a sample

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestCase {

  private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);

  @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
  public void testMethod(String s) {
    if (counter.getAndIncrement() == 2) {
      System.err.println("Debug mode on"); //Set a breakpoint on this line
    }
    System.err.println("Hello " + s);

  }

  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] getData() {
    return new Object[][]{
        {"TestNG"},{"Spring"},{"Selenium"}
    };
  }

}
```

> As an aside, does this code look like an anti-pattern or bad practice ?

I dont think a lot can be said by just looking at the skeleton code. There's hardly anything in the sample that you shared that we can use to suggest.

Comment: Thanks ! I wish there was  a better way to be able to debug without having to add temporary code. But, this works.